# django models Changing the model details

Tags: django, models

If I change certain attributes of a model, say add a column or change the type (or) size constraint etc, then I do

```
python manage.py sql myapp
python manage.py syncdb
```

The change doesnt get effected in the app. The change is effected only if i delete the table from my sql and give the commands again.

Is this the only way or are there any other easy ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Get [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/) and use it to migrate changes.

It's one of the most used django projects in the world and does exactly what you need.

Instead of running

```
python manage.py sycndb
```

You run

```
python manage.py schemamigration appname --initial
```

or

```
python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
```

Or any of the other command combos. Check them out.